# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [12811], [93233]

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ora-00600

I got this while trying to execute

```
            File f = new File("file location");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            PreparedStatement ps = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table (title,file,id) VALUES('title',?,7)");
            ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int)f.length());
            ps.execute();
            ps.close();
```

title - VARCHAR2
file - BLOB
id - FK to another table

Operations with another tables are working, everything is fine but this one. I tried to change statement, drop and recreate table. Without result

Comment: According to Oracle's FAQ - "Every occurrence of an ORA-600 should be reported to Oracle Support. Unlike other errors, you can not find help text for these errors. Only Oracle technical support should diagnose and take actions to prevent or resolve damage to the database."

Comment: yeah, but oracle support is not for free